# Updating the value of an array of objects stored in Recoil js

Tags: recoiljs

Currently I am storing a list of post in my recoil state and I would like to be able to update the title of a post by its id and see the change in realtime.

On the docs I saw an example on how to remove an object from the array and that worked fine but what If I wanted to update the value of an object in the array?

This is what I've been looking at on the docs, but this example just iterates a number.
https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/useRecoilState

The structure of my state that is storing the posts is as follows:

```
[
 {
  id: 1
  title: "test 1"
  desc: ""
 },
{
  id: 2
  title: "test 2"
  desc: ""
 },
{
  id: 3
  title: "test 3"
  desc: ""
 }
]
```

This is my current attempt but i am getting the error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

```
setArticles(prevState => ({
            todoItems: prevState.todoItems.map(
              post => post.id === id ? { ...post, title: 'New Title' }: post
            )
          }))
```

...Any help on how I would write my set state would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you try ```useSetRecoilState()``` ?

Comment: @MohsenMahoski Thanks for the suggestion but the docs say that If i do use that then I wont be subscribed to Realtime changes and I want to do this in a way that updates on the frontend instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useRecoilState, atom, RecoilRoot } from 'recoil';

const listState = atom({
  key: 'listState',
  default: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'test 1',
      desc: '',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'test 2',
      desc: '',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'test 3',
      desc: '',
    },
  ],
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <TextInput />
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}

function TextInput() {
  let [list, setList] = useRecoilState(listState);

  const onChange = (event, id) => {
    let newList = [...list].map((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) return { ...item, title: event.target.value };
      else return item;
    });

    setList(newList);
  };

  return list.map((item) => (
    <div key={item.id}>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={item.title}
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e, item.id)}
      />
      <br />
      Echo: {item.title}
    </div>
  ));
}
```

---

---

Comment: this link for test online : https://react-mvten8.stackblitz.io

Comment: Holy crap, that's... messy, inflexible, unintuitive, and asking for errors to be introduced into the process. Is this really how it must be done?

Comment: It's not great, would re-render your whole list since its a new list